# make: excluding main.c from rule that .o file depends on .h file

Tags: c, makefile

I have a C project with a bunch of source files and their headers:

```
one.c
one.h
two.c
two.h
```

I also have a main.c, but that has no .h file with it:

```
main.c
```

I have this in my Makefile:

```
# Use gcc to make object files from C files.
_build/%.o: %.c %.h
    @mkdir -p _build
    @echo
    @echo Compiling $<
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

This is fine for one.o and two.o. But it's no good for main.o, which does not have a main.h on which to depend. Make then throws this error.

```
make: *** No rule to make target `_build/main.o', needed by `all'.  Stop.
```

How can I best treat main.c specially?

Comment: Why not just go the normal route of making the targets dependent only on the header files the source files actually include?

Comment: You might find [`$(filter-out)`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html#index-filter_002dout) useful.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Would love to. How do I do that?

Comment: @Eliot : using the dependency generation approach in the current answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a separate static pattern rule

```
_build/%.o: %.c
    @mkdir -p _build
    @echo
    @echo Compiling $<
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

_build/one.o _build/two.o: _build/%.o: %.h
```

Even better, use dependency generation

```
OBJS := $(addprefix _build/,main.o one.o two.o)
DEPS := $(OBJS:.o=.d)

CPPFLAGS := -MMD -MP

.PHONY: all clean
all: $(OBJS)

$(OBJS): _build/%.o: %.c | _build
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

_build: ; mkdir -p $@

clean: ; $(RM) -r _build

-include $(DEPS)
```

Comment: How come there's no mention of .h files in your dependency generation approach?

Comment: @Eliot Because that's the whole purpose of dependency generation, the .h files appear in the rules generated by GCC which are then included in the main makefile.

Comment: OK, thanks. You can probably guess from the question that I did not understand auto dependency generation in make till now. Have read up on the it and the -MMD and -MP flags to gcc and the -include $(DEPS) thing (which are the important bits of the above for anyone else confused by this).